# Code inside the constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have the following Java class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private List<MyObject> lst;

    public MyClass(){
        //----Starting initial code-----
        MyAdditionalObject obj=new MyAdditionalObject();
        Event e= new Event()
        obj.attacheEvent(e);
        //----initial code end-----
        lst.add(e);
    }
}
```

Is it a bad practice to put such initial code inside the constructor?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might like to look up SOLID principles of design and particularly coupling.  Testing would be harder here too.  But that all being said it depends. This question is a bit subjective. ^^ Well, as Reimeus says there's "a place for that on ere"

Comment: Instance initialization block will be a good option here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Initialization block if you have overloaded constructor to avoid repetition of code.

```
public class MyClass{
   private List<MyObject> lst;

   //Initialization block
   {
       //----Starting initial code-----
       MyAdditionalObject obj=new MyAdditionalObject();
       Event e= new Event()
       obj.attacheEvent(e);
       //----initial code end-----
   }

   public MyClass(){...}

   public MyClass(int i){...}

   public MyClass(String i){...}

}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I have one question about it: Did you mean that initialiation blocks execute before the constructor?

Comment: I dont know what the equivalent in Java is but couldnt you just call the base constructor from all of the others.  Eg C#  : base()

Comment: Why is this preferable over chained constructors?

Comment: Yes initialization blocks always execute before any constructor.

Comment: @Braj. Would you stick external dependencies in that init block too? You couldnt could you?

Comment: Yes you can't pass the constructor arguments to initialization block but its sole purpose is to prepare the data before constructing the object that is independent of any external factor.

Comment: How can I access to a variables of the initial block from constructor's body?

Comment: You can't as I said in my last comment. initialization block is called before constructor code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternative to using a constructor to initialize instance members...

**First one** is **Instance initialization block**,

```
{
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
    MyAdditionalObject obj=new MyAdditionalObject();
    Event e= new Event()
    obj.attacheEvent(e);
}
```

The reason that instance initialization block is recommended over chaining of constructor is

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

So, approach will be simpler and will reduce the vertical problem.

**Second one** is to use **final method** to initialize instance members. A final method cannot be overridden in a subclass.

Example :

```
class Whatever {
    private varType myVar = initializeInstanceVariable();

    protected final varType initializeInstanceVariable() {

        // initialization code goes here
        MyAdditionalObject obj=new MyAdditionalObject();
        Event e= new Event()
        obj.attacheEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Reference Java doc for answer : [Initializing fields.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Writing unnecessary code can be referred as "Vertical Problem". Bulkiness of code in other words. Mentioned in [State of Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html)